# use different python version (3.8) and virtual environment in VSC workspace (sub)folder only

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyenv

I would like to use a different version of Python (3.8.0) and a dedicated virtual environment in a subfolder of a VSC project/work space. Is this possible? Any pointers would be very much appreciated. Thus far U tried to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTx18uyyHw8) using pyenv.

I ran:

```
pyenv local 3.8.0
python -m venv .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate
```

in the VSC terminal but when I run:

```
(.venv) PS C:\blaproject> python -V
```

I still get:

```
Python 3.10.4
```

Is there a step I missed? There is a .python-version file containing 3.8.0 but ..venv\Scripts\activate does not seem to use this and stick, in my case, with Python 3.10.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The lower right corner of VS code will display the current interpreter version.**

[image]

Then, we need to understand one thing, the terminal in VS code uses the built-in **powershell** of Windows, so when you use the `python -m venv .venv` command in the VS code terminal to create a new virtual environment, the `python` at this time points to the python version configured by the environment variable in your machine. Same as you use `python` command in external **cmd** window or **poweshell**.

For example, at this time, my Windows environment variable is configured with the path of `python310`

[image]

then I use the `python -m venv .venv310` command in the vscode terminal to create a new virtual environment, and the python version of the virtual environment is `3.10.4`.

[image]

If you need to use other versions, you can modify the windows environment variables, or you can directly specify the path of the python version in the command.

For example, I use the following command to specify the `python3.9` version to create a new virtual environment,

```
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\python.exe -m venv .venv39
```

[image]

***PS:*** Click the interpreter version in the lower right corner to choose to switch between different interpreters.

[image]

*After switching, you can create a new terminal to activate the environment.*

Comment: thanks for this amazing and exhausting post. so are you saying I could have an older version of Python (3.8) installed "quietly" and can run C:\bla\python.exe -m venv .venv3.8 and do not need pyenv?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you with my answer. Where do you have questions? If you want to create a virtual environment of `python3.8`, that's what you said `C:\bla\python.exe -m venv .venv3.8`.

Comment: so is there no need for pyenv?

Comment: no need. Did you try it? Maybe run it and you will know if you need it or not.

Comment: `.venv39` is simply a folder name and has nothing to do with versioning. `python -V` will tell you the version that venv will create. The fact that you have 5+ versions of Python in your AppData folder is a bit concerning