# i use python 3.10 how should i create a python 3.8 virtual environment in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm using python 3.10 in vs code and i have to create a project using python 3.8 so how could i create a virtual environment with python 3.8?

i tried in the vs code command prompt python -m venv venv, it is creating the environment but i cannot find the required version of python.

Comment: Python 3.10 should be able to run code from Python 3.8 with minimal changes... Why do you need to downgrade?

Comment: i was creating a project watching on youtube in that he specifically uses python3.8 in vscode using conda create python ==3.8 venv

Comment: Just because the YouTube presenter is using Python 3.8 doesn't necessarily mean *you* need to as well.

Comment: i thought i will get to learn new things so that's the reason, anyway thankyou so much sir i appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use different python version (3.8) and virtual environment in VSC workspace (sub)folder only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713231/use-different-python-version-3-8-and-virtual-environment-in-vsc-workspace-sub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install python 3.8 to create environments of it.

For example, use `pyenv` to easily manage this, and Vscode knows how to detect a pyenv setup (e.g. `.python-version` file in the project).

Comment: okk, can i can i install while creating a venv in vscode?

Comment: Vscode uses your current interpreter to create a venv, so no

Comment: and how should i use pyenv?

Comment: @Shubhamyadav use the full path to your Python 3.8 interpreter while creating the virtual environment